# Gradle throws: Unable to establish loopback connection

Tags: gradle

Gradle throws exception with message "Unable to establish loopback connection".  The following is the stack trace thrown at the console.

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection                            
org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection                                                                   
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)                                                                         
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.<init>(SocketConnection.java:58)                                                   
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnectCompletion.create(SocketConnectCompletion.java:43)                                                 
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.connect(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:92)                               
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.ForkingTestClassProcessor.forkProcess(ForkingTestClassProcessor.java:78)                                     
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.ForkingTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(ForkingTestClassProcessor.java:56)                                
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.processors.RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(RestartEveryNTestClassProcessor.java:45)                
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                  
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)                                                                     
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)                             
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)                                                                     
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)                                                                     
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:29)                                                           
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:132)                                                                      
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:33)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:72)     
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)                                         
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)                                                                           
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)                                                                           
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

### Gradle version :

### Gradle 1.12

Build time:   2014-04-29 09:24:31 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     a831fa866d46cbee94e61a09af15f9dd95987421

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_45 (Oracle Corporation 24.45-b08)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 x86

Jdk is 1.7.45.

Is there any help? I tried stopping the anti virus assuming the connection are getting terminated by AV. However, the issue re-occurred when the AV was turned off.

Comment: Could you please add the output produced by running the same command with the `--info` flag?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a problem where Gradle cannot connect to the gradle Daemon. Your machine probably has an issue with its networking config, which needs to be worked out.

A possible workaround would be to run without the Daemon, using the `--no-daemon` option. If that still doesn't work, there is some other reason why it tries to establish a connection, probably due to a custom plugin or build script.

Answer (score 0):

I was using JDK v1.7.0_45 and I now use 1.7.0_79. Ever since the upgrade I am not observing this issue. I switched back to v1.7.0_45 this morning and I am already noticed "Unable to establish loopback connection" twice out of six iterations.